# Double.ToString() behaviour is not consistent

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

Im converting a string to double and then splitting the converted value as shown below.

```
double.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double convertedValue);
var splitValue = convertedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The behavior of the above code snippet is different when run from Nunit testcase and from the application.

for example:

if stringValue="0.000000000000000000003402823499999999""

when run from n-nunit:

```
         convertedValue = 3.4028234999999987E-21            
         splitValue[0]= "3";
         splitValue[1] = "4028235E-21"
```

When run from the application

```
        convertedValue = 3.40282349999999E-21                
        splitValue[0]= "3";
        splitValue[1] = "40282349999999E-21"
```

I wanted to understand the reason for this behavior ?

Comment: Are you running both in debug or release mode (optimized)?

Comment: You got 3.4028235E-21 if you ran the code on .net framwork or .net core < 3. The default precision is 15 digits on these platforms.

Comment: (a) Why does your “run from the application” show two “convertedValue = ” lines? (b) What software is printing this “convertedValue =” output? Is it something in your program or some debugger/monitor you are using to examine the code or what? (c) If `double.TryParse` is producing two different values, why does your title implicate `double.ToString`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I observed these values while debugging . double.TryParse produces value which are almost same . The issue I'm facing is when i try to convert and split by using ToString() and split . The value is getting rounded

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with `double.ToString` here. From memory about how Microsoft software behaves, it is either formatting the number to 15 significant digits and then removing trailing zeros or it is producing just enough digits to uniquely distinguish the number printed from neighboring `double` values. In both cases, it has produced correct output for the input it was given. The actual cause of the different numbers is that `double.TryParse` produced different results.

Comment: Can you please check the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription` property for both test & prod environments? I suspect that it will not match.

Comment: @EricPostpischil convertedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split results in "4028235E-21" in one case and "40282349999999E-21" in the other . I wanted this behavior to be consistent

Comment: @harin04: No, it does not, at least not in the examples you have shown. The first example, labeled “when run from n-nunit”, shows that when the value shown as `3.4028234999999987E-21` is input to `double.ToString`, it results in `4028235E-21`. The second example, labeled “When run from the application”, shows that when the value shown as `3.40282349999999E-21` is input to `double.ToString`, it results in `40282349999999E-21`. Thus these two examples demonstrate that `double.ToString` produces different outputs for different inputs, which is normal.

Comment: The actual origin of the different numbers is whatever caused `convertedValue` to have the value (as displayed) of `3.4028234999999987E-21` in one case and `3.40282349999999E-21` in another case. Those are different numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ok. How do i make double.TryParse to be consistent ?